# Size New Window to Content and Center Relative to Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button that opens a `New Window`.

I want to fit the `New Window` to the dynamic content inside.

Then position it `Center`, relative to `Main Window`. So it follows the `Main Window`'s location.

Not `WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen`.

---

This is what I'm using. It doesn't quite work right.

**XAML**

The `New Window` is originally set to 900x500, but is overridden by `SizeToContent`.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.NewWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="New Window" 
        Width="900"
        Height="500">
```

**C#**

This Button is on `Main Window`.

I use `SizeToContent.Width`.

`newWindow.Width` does not use the `SizeToContent`'s width, but instead detects the `XAML` width `900`.

This causes the `New Window` to always be off center.

I tried setting the `XAML` width to `Auto` or `1`, it still goes off center a different direction.

I tried using `double width = Convert.ToInt32(SizeToContent.Width);` but it says the width is `1`.

I ran `newWindow.UpdateLayout()` but it didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149676/6806643

```
public static NewWindow newWindow;

private Boolean IsNewWindowOpened = false;

private void btnNeWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
        // Check if Window is already open
        if (IsNewWindowOpened) return;

        newWindow = new NewWindow(this);

        // Only allow 1 Window instance
        newWindow.ContentRendered += delegate { IsNewWindowOpened = true; };
        newWindow.Closed += delegate { IsNewWindowOpened = false; };

        // Keep Window on Top
        newWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);

        // Fit Window to Content
        newWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Width;

        // Update Layout
        newWindow.UpdateLayout()

        // Detect which screen we're on
        var allScreens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.ToList();
        var thisScreen = allScreens.SingleOrDefault(s => this.Left >= s.WorkingArea.Left && this.Left < s.WorkingArea.Right);
        if (thisScreen == null) thisScreen = allScreens.First();

        // Position Relative to MainWindow
        newWindow.Left = Math.Max((this.Left + (this.Width - newWindow.Width) / 2), thisScreen.WorkingArea.Left);
        newWindow.Top = Math.Max((this.Top + (this.Height - newWindow.Height) / 2), thisScreen.WorkingArea.Top);

        // Open Window
        newWindow.Show();
}
```

---

**Examples**

Off Center

[image: off center]

---

Correctly Centered

[image: center]

Comment: Probably you need to count dpi too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931333/wpf-converting-between-screen-coordinates-and-wpf-coordinates

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy I can't get it to work, `corner.X` always returns `0`. It goes off the screen. The second solution jumps all over the screen.

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy With some more tweaking I got https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045871/6806643 to center with `SizeToContent.Width`. Though `newWindow.Show()` before `OnContentRendered()` causes it to glitch across the screen into place.

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy I solved the glitch by placing the positioning in `Window_Loaded` instead of `OnContentRendered()` inside newWindow. I'll write up a solution after testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done. Let me know if you have any improvements.

#### Main Window

Open New Window Button

```
public static NewWindow newWindow;

private Boolean IsNewWindowOpened = false;

private void btnNeWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    if (IsPreviewWindowOpened) return;

    // Open Preview Window
    previewWindow = new Preview(this);

    // Only allow 1 Window instance
    previewWindow.ContentRendered += delegate { IsPreviewWindowOpened = true; };
    previewWindow.Closed += delegate { IsPreviewWindowOpened = false; };

    // Keep Window on Top
    previewWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);

    // Size to Content
    previewWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Width;

    // Open Window
    previewWindow.Show();
}
```

---

#### New Window

**XAML**

Window_Loaded

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.NewWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="New Window" 
        Width="900"
        Height="500"

        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

**C#**

Size Window to fit dynamic content.
Position Center, relative to Main Window.

Also nudges window back on screen if going off.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Detect which screen we're on
    var allScreens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.ToList();
    var thisScreen = allScreens.SingleOrDefault(s => this.Left >= s.WorkingArea.Left && this.Left < s.WorkingArea.Right);
    if (thisScreen == null) thisScreen = allScreens.First();

    // Position Relative to MainWindow
    this.Left = Math.Max((mainwindow.Left + (mainwindow.Width - this.Width) / 2), thisScreen.WorkingArea.Left);
    this.Top = Math.Max((mainwindow.Top + (mainwindow.Height - this.Height) / 2), thisScreen.WorkingArea.Top);
}
```